# twitter bootstrap accordion effect not working for menu

Tags: angularjs

I have parent menu with sub menus, but the accordion effect is not working for menus.(if second menu link clicks, automatically the first menu should close)

I have created the code in plunker,

http://plnkr.co/edit/yCO19F8f29tipZoM5uII?p=preview

### view

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper"> 
    <ul class="panel sidebar-nav" ng-repeat="item in model | orderBy:'sortOrder'">
    <li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle mainMenu menuArrow" href="javascript:void(0)" >{{item.description}}
     <i class="sub_icon fa fa-lg fa-fw {item.iconTarget}}"></i>
   </a>
   <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
     <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.children">
        <a href="#{{subitem.target}}" class="subTitle"> {{subitem.description}} </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use AngularJS `ng-Class` to switch class. Don't have more time If I have I show an example in answer [angular ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: Hi Mac,  it is working if i use static content instead of dynamic

Comment: Looks like you're missing some of the attributes needed for the bootstrap accordion. You should check your code against this link:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### back, (after a hard day...) and as promise :

- better than `ng-Class` (like I said earlier), I suggest **Angular UI** (**Twitter Bootstrap written natively in AngularJS**)

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
   <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
   <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <script>

  //here in your javascript file (here is a demo)    
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);     
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {


  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

      $scope.model = [
        {
            "code": "401",
            "description": "Transactions",
            "labelName": null,
            "target": null,
            "children": [
                {
                    "description": "Deposit Funds",
                    "target": "transds",
                    "children": null
                },
                {
                    "description": "Withdraw Funds",
                    "target": "fdfdfs",
                    "children": null
                  }
              ]
           },
          {
            "code": "403",

               "description": "Cash Management",
               "labelName": null,
               "target": null,
               "children": [
                 {
                       "description": "Head Cashier - Entry",
                       "target": "ccry.html",
                       "children": null
                },
                {
                    "description": "Head Cashier - Verify",
                    "target": "ccg.html",
                    "children": null
                }
            ]
        }
     ];

  });      

   </script>


  </head>
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
    Open only one at a time
  </label>
  <p>Example amazing angular accordion</p>



   <accordion close-others="oneAtATime" >
     <div ng-repeat="item in model | orderBy:'sortOrder'">
     <accordion-group>
       <accordion-heading>
         {{item.description}} <i class="sub_icon fa fa-lg fa-fw {{item.iconTarget}}"></i>
       </accordion-heading>

       <div ng-repeat="subitem in item.children">
           <a href="#{{subitem.target}}" class="subTitle"> {{subitem.description}} </a>
       </div>
     </accordion-group>
     </div>
   </accordion>


   </div>
   </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Next I let you apply your own css and move js in a file.

Answer (score 1):

finally its working fine with small change,

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="accordion">
      <ul class="panel sidebar-nav" ng-repeat="item in model | orderBy:'sortOrder'" id="sidebar{{$index}}">
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mainMenu menuArrow collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#child{{$index}}" ng-click="model.selected = item">{{item.description}}
             <i class="sub_icon fa fa-lg fa-fw {{item.iconTarget}}"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="child{{$index}}" data-menu-title="{{item.description}}" ng-class="{'collapse':true}">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.children">
             <a href="#{{subitem.target}}" class="subTitle"> {{subitem.description}} </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, this solution was the one I was looking for before switching easy Angular UI.The trick I didn't implement was id="child{{$index}}"